# Front Side Bus improvements

Tags: fsb

What would be the effect of doubling the number of bits in the FSB? As far as I understand, the FSB does not scale well and the HyperTransport Bus is a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the FSB"? There have been a number of different FSB implementations and it's not clear what exactly you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the point of the question is but here's your answer:

> What would be the effect of doubling the number of bits in the FSB?

You'd double the bandwidth – i.e. you could transfer twice the amount of information in a clock cycle.

> As far as I understand, the FSB does not scale well and the HyperTransport Bus is a better solution

Your understanding is correct.